# Use Wordpress custom post in a contact form

Tags: wordpress, contact-form

I have created custom post type "Product" in Wordpress and I would like to use Products within my contact form. For example, I would like to have a drop down that is a list of all of my Products so users can select a Product name as the message's Subject. I have Contact Form 7 installed. Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I think the short answer is no. There is not an easy way to do this. The Contact Form 7 plugin  uses shortcodes to construct the select lists. What you need to do is run a query on your Posts -> Products and generate your own select list. I suppose what I would do is write my own shortcode function. Then you can include it in your page.

```
[myProductsShortCode]
```

Then you can iterate through that result set and generate your own select list.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

http://codex.wordpress.org/wpdb#query_-_Run_Any_Query_on_the_Database

Comment: It is better to use `WP_Query` or get_posts to create a dropdown - it is closer to 'wordpress way'.

Comment: Yes you are right. Thank you. http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters

Answer (score 1):

People seem to be able to add custom information [like that, from](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-add-new-custom-shortcode)

```
    function test_generator() {
    /* need to produce html like this:
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap menu-645"><select name="menu-645" class="wpcf7-select"><option value="one">one</option><option value="two">two</option></select></span>
    so here we go:     */
    $list = "<span class=\"wpcf7-form-control-wrap menu-test\"><select name=\"menu-test\" class=\"wpcf7-select\"><option value=\"test1\">test-1</option><option value=\"test2\">test-2</option></select></span>";
    return $list;
    }
    wpcf7_add_shortcode('test', 'test_generator');
```

and then just use [test] in the contactform